# Delete an SMS in Android before it reaches the inbox?

Tags: android, sms

Create your custom broadcast receiver to receive sms. write the logic to abort the boradcast so that the message will not be available to your inbox

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
   this.abortBroadcast();
  }
}
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Not working any suggestion ...
Still show notification and message reaching in inbox

Answer (score 4):

They removed this ability several versions ago.  Only the chosen SMS app of the user can delete messages or prevent them from hitting the inbox.

Comment: Can you share any example, how can i stop default sms notification.

Comment: @SanaanChattha this means your app has to be the default SMS app. You can't have an app that isn't the default SMS app and delete the SMSes